# Buying multiple consumable in app items at the same time

Tags: android, android-billing

Is it possible to purchase the same item, multiple times?

Let's say the user want to buy 200 coins through an in app purchase. Do I have to have two different managed products to let users buy 100 and 200 coins. Or Can I simply multiple the 100 coins product by 2?

Comment: @ZUNJAE What is it called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the [description of the INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA extra](http://www.androiddocs.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#purchase-data-table), this is not supported: a single purchase contains a single productId, and no quantity.

So there is no way to purchase 5 copies of the same product at once, and there is no way to purchase multiple products that sum up to the desired quantity simultaneously either.